# performance benefit of script and style inside DOM

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, dom

I'm building a website using PHP templates.

I have a lot of outside CSS libs and stylesheets and they are linked to the main HTML document with `<link rel="stylesheet">` (the way they are supposed to be).

I do the same with external scripts (`<script src="...">`).

Is there a benefit in concatenating all the resources above into one block of text and inserting it directly into the main document with PHP?

Example:

```
<html>
   <head>
     <style>
       <?php echo $style; // Huge block of CSS (maybe 300KB) ?>
     </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    ....
     <script>
       <?php echo $scripts; // Also pretty big maybe 500KB ?>
     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm aware that this will remove the benefits of caching those resources by the client. I think however, that it will give me a benefit with initial loading times since less connections are required to fetch the resources.

Will I be facing any performance bottlenecks from the DOM?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do want to optimize the load time of the very first time a user visits any page in your site while not optimized all subseuqent pages?  Or do you want to optimize the average load time as they browser your site.  Usually, folks want the latter which says to use external files so you can benefit from local browser caching across pages.  Also, the newest version of HTTP will allow multiple resources to be requested in parallel over the same TCP connection.

Comment: I want ease of development. Such a structure allows me to add / remove scripts from all pages (footer and header are individual templates) as I see fit without going into individual HTML files.

Comment: I'm aware of no reason that using linked stylesheets is less easy to develop.  In fact, I think most people think it's easier to develop because it's simpler to share stylesheets between pages.

Answer (score 0):

I know that these kind of processes can be monitored using a number of different browser attachments including the native web monitor in most browsers.

I cannot tell you off the top of my head, but I would assume that may actually increase the load time since PHP is processed prior to the HTML.

Check out: http://getfirebug.com/

Using that tool you can check the connection times and adjust accordingly.